# How to achieve the automated test case for remember me functionality

Tags: java, selenium

I have a username, password and remember me checkbox, how can I verify that once user has logged in and close the browser with remember me ticked on, the next time they login, user should directly be taken to the logged in dashboard. How to test this in selenium.

All the available solution are either outdated or not working

Comment: that's basically functionality of cookie , Have you tried that ?

Comment: yes I tried that but it is not working..  I am trying the following code-  Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();

        driver.close();

        //open a new browser window
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //restore all cookies from previous session
        for(Cookie cookie : allCookies) {
            driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
        }
and then calling the driver.get() for the web, but i am getting following error- org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unable to set cookie

Comment: Now my cookie is working but it is not serving the purpose, it is not testing the functionality of "remember me", it is just copying the cookie of one session and then rendering it to another new session, there is not role of remember me checkbox in the above code

Comment: try to write the same cookie for gmail.com and use it , it'd help you to understand the functionality of cookie.

Comment: You can go ahead with @Murthi solution too. sounds like good workaround for the given scenario.

Comment: @cruisepandey Hi, so I have understood the functionality of cookie, that it stores user info and when you send the same cookie in a new browser same set of info is loaded, now the problem is that the checkbox value doesn't hae any impact on it, the cookie is sending username and password hence user is already logged in in the new session.

Comment: Yes you are right , and it should not have any impact of remember me , because the sole purpose of cookies are to store information like Name, value , path , created , expire , size , http , etc.  So that It will help us resume the operations where we left off , remember our registered login  and all.

Comment: The website you are automating is public or it's internal ? If it's public I can have a look and might provide you solution too.

Comment: It is  internal.. Also because as we discussed that the cookie would not help, is there any other way by which I can check the functionality? I hope you understand what I actually want to test

Answer (score 2):

By default, selenium create new profile each time it launches the browser. So when we save the credentials, the information is stored with profile location. So it will not be available for next session.

To overcome above issue, you can create a profile and load it with selenium every time. So if we click on remember me, it will store in the profile location. So next time you launch it, then it will be loaded.

I am not tried it yet, it is my idea only. You can try and let me know.

Comment: sounds quite logical to me !

Comment: @Murthi can you please guide me with this profile location, can you please elaborate the solution, I didnt understand what this profile is and how it will help in checking the functionality of remember me

Comment: chrome or firefox loads the default profile which is a place all configuration and other data resides when we launch it manually. But selenium launches browsers with new profile every time. When we click on remember me the credential info is stored in the profile location. And It uses that info when we launches second time. but selenium uses different profile each time. It couldn't get the stored credentials next time. If we make selenium to use the same profile every time it will be able to get stored credentials again.

Comment: Correct but in that case user's password and name would also be saved hence again it won't matter whether the user has marked the checkbox or not, what I want to test is that when I have unchecked the remember me checkbox and load the website then login page should be displayed and when I am ticking it and close the browser and reload it then the logged in page should be loaded

Comment: Yes, that's true for when we do it manually as well. To overcome this, you can use two profiles one checked and another for unchecked. Otherwise you need to create the profile with code and save it and delete after your test.

Comment: @kritikaagarwal, did you achieve your purpose ? If yes how ? I have created a custome profile for chrome, still every time user name and password is required, when launched through selenium.