# How to check remember_me checkbox of Jenkins login page using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I cannot check-in the user credentials encrypt/decrypt logic, to the git, so for now we are copying the class files on CI machines. But it has dependency to contact IT team for copy access.
Approach I am thinking is like - create a customer chrome profile, launch it using selenium chrome driver, on Jenkins login page, add user name, password and click remember me.  I hope this setting will persisted to next chrome session as well.  But, somehow the code is not able check the checkbox. It do identify it but no click.

1. I have tried by suing wait, maximize the window, still get the error as :

org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (764, 504). Other element would receive the click: ...

Code I am using :

```
driver.get(input_params.get("JenkinsURL")); 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement remember_me = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='remember_me']"));
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
remember_me.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below. It worked for me.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("URL");
    WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/form/div[4]/label/div[1]"));
    checkbox.click();
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Arpita, Sonali. Thanks solution worked. But somehow the user credentials field is empty when the script re-run even after remember me is clicked. Any help in this case ?

Comment: @Mandar Kale: For that need to create a profile to store the credentials of the previous session. For more details please refer to the link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250424/how-to-achieve-the-automated-test-case-for-remember-me-functionality

Answer (score 1):

Please use the xpath as below:
`//div[@class='Checkbox-indicator']//*[local-name(0='svg']`